# Facebook get random friends photo and name

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am using the code bellow to get a random friend from user and everything works great.. I need to implement this and i need and the name of this user.

The problem is that while friends photo is ok, the name is different from the friend's photo. It's random.

My code:

```
function getFriendRandom(cb) {
  FB.api('/me/friends',{
      fields: 'name,id,picture.width(400).height(400)'
    }, function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
     var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*response.data.length);
     var thefrienam = response.data.length;
     cb(response.data[random].picture.data.url + "|" + response.data[random].name);

    }
  });
}
```

And usage:

```
getFriendRandom(function(image){
var the_string = image;
var parts = the_string.split('|', 2);
var fimagef = parts[0];
var yourfriendsname = parts[1];
});
```

any idea please how to get the correct name of each random friend?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] You can fake the data but have it in the correct order

Comment: FYI/OT: Concatenating two pieces of data together to pass them to a callback function, only to then in there split them into the original values again, is rather nonsense. In general, use arrays in cases like this. Here specifically you might as well just pass `response.data[random]` into the callback function, and then access the properties `picture.data.url` and `name` there.